# attachBrowserEvent KeyPress, Backspace is not working in Chrome

Tags: sapui5

Currently, I have a TextArea which I attach the keypress-Event of the browser.

```js
MyTextArea.attachBrowserEvent("keypress", keyPressed);
```

In the method "keyPressed", I'm preventing the default event.
like this: `e.preventDefault();`

However, my problem is that the "BACKSPACE" key is not working in Chrome.

In Chrome, when I press "BACKSPACE", it is executed, however my method "keyPressed" is not executed. It works fine in Firefox.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this issue?
I'm preventing this, since I'm using another language written from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *keypress* event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value, *KeyDown* event is raised for all including nonprintable such as `Control`, `Shift`, `Alt`, `BackSpace`, etc.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

So, I would suggest to use *keydown* instead.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/sefova/1/edit?html,js,output) is working example.

Comment: :) Thanks Dopedev, it works now, I will keep in mind the KeyDown-Event for nonprintable keys.